# extra error in call? Swift2 issue with CoreData app

Tags: ios, swift, core-data

I am trying to convert this code

```
var request = NSFetchRequest(entityName: "ItemModel")
    var error: NSError?

    var results : NSArray = managedObjectContext!.executeFetchRequest(request, error: &error)!

    for res in results
    {
        println(res)
    }
    self.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)

}
```

for my application into SWIFT2 however am having no luck. This is my attempt to convert it.

```
do {

        let results = try self.context!.executeFetchRequest(fetchRequest) as! [ItemModel]

    } catch {
        fatalError("getItem error: /(fetchError.localizedDescription)")
    }

}
```

I am trying to use this to Fetch Data from my Core Data named Item Model however am seriously struggling. Does anyone know what I am doing wrong? I get no errors with my new code but it doesnt run.

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
func fetchItems() -> [NSManagedObject]? {

    let managedContext = // your context here

    let fetchRequest = NSFetchRequest(entityName: "ItemModel")

    do {
        let results = try managedContext.executeFetchRequest(fetchRequest)
        return results as? [NSManagedObject]
    } catch let error as NSError {
        print("Could not fetch \(error), \(error.userInfo)")
    }
    return nil
}
```

then you assemble your `ItemObject` array from the results of the function. Your objects are not stored in the DB as `ItemObject`s, they are converted to `NSManagedObject`s and you have to reconvert them after fetching them from the DB.

For example, say your ItemObject class looks like this:

```
class ItemObject {

    var name : String
    var someData : NSData
}
```

You would recreate these items like so:

```
func convertObjects(objects: [NSManagedObject]) -> [ItemObject] {

    var itemObjects = [ItemObject]()

    for object in objects {

        let itemObject = ItemObject()

        itemObject.name = object.valueForKey("NAME_KEY") as? String ?? "DEFAULT_VALUE"
        itemObject.someData = object.valueForKey("DATA_KEY") as? NSData ?? NSData()

        itemObjects.append(itemObject)
    }
    return itemObjects
}
```